# Discord.net send DMs to a specific user?

Tags: c#, dsharp+

So i've been searching for all day for a method that sends to a specific user a private message. I'm making a ticket system and I need to print all tickets in DM to the person that executed the command.

```
        [Command("createtickets")]
    [Description("Creates tickets")]
    public async Task createtickets(CommandContext ctx)
    {

        var interactivity = ctx.Client.GetInteractivity();

        string filepath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.txt";

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToList();

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        string[] chars = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "k", "z", "n", "u", "r", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i< 9; i++)
        {
            string randomString = "";
            for (int j = 0; j<12; j++)
            {
                randomString = randomString + chars[rnd.Next(0, 21)];
            }
            lines.Add(randomString);
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(filepath,lines);

        await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("10 Tickets were written");

        var user = ctx.User;
```

As you can see there is a list with all the tickets and that is the thing i need to send via DM. I've tried searching on youtube, Discord.net Docs, DSharpplus Docs, every forum on the internet but they all list functions that were probably removed on the recent versions. Can anyone help me with this? I just need a way to DM the user

Comment: Just call `SendMessage` on the `User` object.... **Edit:** on second look, this isn't `Discord.Net`, please only tag your questions with relevant tags. I'm not sure why you'd search docs for a lib you aren't using, but he DNet docs are definitely not out of date. **Edit2:** There is a [similar method](https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/api/DSharpPlus.Entities.DiscordMember.html#DSharpPlus_Entities_DiscordMember_SendMessageAsync_System_String_System_Boolean_DSharpPlus_Entities_DiscordEmbed_) in DSharpPlus

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that the Class DiscordUser doesn't have the method SendMessageAsync(), I solved casting the ctx.user to DiscordMember. Sorry for the miscomprehension but i thought that this included discord.net, i'll remove the tag.